# how to insert data from a select box using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have come across a problem when inserting values from a html select in to a mysql database. I can't seem to get the values to insert for some reason; I have looked for help on this but they keep giving me errors.
Also, can some please tell me what the difference between mysql and mysqli?

php code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","barsne","bit me");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("testing", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO client_details (id, f_name, l_name, phone, email, job_est) VALUES
   ('', '$_POST[f_name]', '$_POST[l_name]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[job_est]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "Thank you for booking a with us we will contact you in the next 24 hours to confirm your booking with a time and date";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

html code

```
<form method="post" action="processing_booking.php">
    <h4><u>Basic Contact Details</u></h4>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="l_name" id="l_name">
    <label>Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

    <h4><u>Job Details</u></h4>
    <label>You Would Like To Book A:</label>
    <select name="job_est">
        <option value="select">--SELECT--</options>
        <option value="job">Job</option>
        <option value="est">Estimation</option>
    </select>

    <label>Service Your Booking:</label>
    <select name="job_type">
        <option value="select">--SELECT--</option>
        <option value="gardening">Gardening</option>
        <option value="landscaping">Landscaping</option>
        <option value="painting">Painting & Decorating</option>
        <option value="decking">Decking & Fencing</option>
    </select>

    <label>Any Additional Information </label>
    <textarea name="extra_info"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="lets get your dreams started">
</form>
```

sorry wirting is not my strong point

Comment: The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). The code is also wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Can you please add the starting form tag also to the question

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: you should never write $_POST values directly in your sql query. Even when it is a selectbox the value can be easily changed with tools like  chrome developer toolbar tampadata etc.

Comment: have you noticed that you're using $_POST[f_name] istead of $_POST['f_name'] ...

Comment: @aaron head what error are you getting?

Comment: no so much error as just a empty value in mysql db i no The code is also wide open to SQL injection i only built a basic insert statement at the min i will adding security to it one i have this problem sorted and is there any thing wrong with using   $_POST[f_name] instead of $_POST['f_name']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `$_POST['name']` you missed `single quotations`

you must prevent from injection with

```
// String Type Fields 
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$f_name= strip_tags($_POST['f_name']);
$l_name= strip_tags($_POST['l_name']);
$phone= strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
$email= strip_tags($_POST['email']);

// Int Type Fields
if (isset($_POST['job_est']) && is_numeric($_POST['job_est']))
   $job_est= $_POST['job_est'];
else 
   $job_est= 0;
```

then use in your query

other point is 
if your id field is primary and auto increment , you can define your query as below :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO client_details (f_name, l_name, phone, email, job_est) VALUES
   ( '".$f_name."', '".$l_name."', '".$phone."', '".$email."', ".$job_est.")";
```

for strings you must use `'".$variable."'`
and for integer or numeric you must use `".$variable."`

other point is you must change your select element to below because you have noticed in your comments your `job_est` field type is `int(11)`

```
<select name="job_est">
    <option value="0">--SELECT--</option>
    <option value="1">Gardening</option>
    <option value="2">Landscaping</option>
    <option value="3">Painting & Decorating</option>
    <option value="4">Decking & Fencing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: put `strip_tags` before `$sql="`

Comment: what is the field type of your `job_est` filed in your db ?

Comment: the job_est is int(11) let me guess as a newibe i made one of the most simplest mistakes

Comment: so you must set the value of `select box` to `integer` and so you dont need `strip tags` the job_est and simply check `if is_nummeric($_POST['job_est'])`. I have updated my answer

Comment: how would i put if is_nummeric($_POST['job_est']) in to my script

Comment: sorry i new to php insert

Comment: i getting this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_nummerc() in /home/slchandy/public_html/prototype/processing_booking.php on line 9

Comment: sorry this is my typing fault : you must change `is_nummeric` to  `is_numeric` at line 9

Comment: sorry did not see you last part of you edited answer is there any way to have it so that words are inserted in to my db because i will not be the only one looking at this when it is up and running

Comment: as you most likey can tell by my coding and the type or form i trying to build this is not my trade i have tired learning from books and the internet

Comment: I could not undrestand your last twoo comments ! I have tried to enter to discussion with you but your reputation is not enough for enter to discussion unfortunately. I Recomment to you before writing any code fist study and read and research about it. then select a solution and finaly go to writing code.

Comment: i am a builder by trade not a web designer and instead of using number to be inserted in to the db i need words as my employees need to be able to read it as well so instead of 1= gardening 2= landscaping i need it to just say landscaping or gardening if you can see what i am say

Comment: you have many ways for handle this . quick and easy way is using php `switch` for example if `job_est` equals to `1` then `echo  "gardening";`

Comment: thank you very much for you time you have been a great help sorry for what seem to be stupid question you have the approved answer

Answer (score 1):

- The mysql functions are deprecated. Use the mysqli or pdo class
  instead.

  mysqli: https://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

  pdo:    https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- Make a `var_dump($_POST)` and you will see what the problem is. By the way you missed the single quotes `$_POST['value']`
- Never ever write $_POST or $_GET data directly in your sql queries. Always validate them before, because even the value of a selectbox can get easily changed with tampadata or chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can obviously start printing the results of your $_POST array with :

`print_r($_POST,1);`

to check all variables existence in it